# Replace Function in SQL in IBMI for Multiple Characters(coming from a table)

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I am facing an issue with Replace function in SQL. I have a table(Table A) which has 2 fields( Original_Char and Replacement_char).
Now for a string I have in the program, I have to replace every character in the Original_char Field , to its corresponding Replacement_char Field.

For Example if I have one record Original_char = 'A' and Replacement_Char = '%’ and If my string is ‘Apple Ball’ then it should be replaced to ‘%pple B%ll’ . Now if I add one more record here, Original_char = 'E' and Replacement_Char = '&', then my string would be ‘‘%ppl& B%ll’’

I tried with replace function in SQL. It would work with one record but Table A can have any number of records and all the Original_char Character of the string should be replaced with Replacement_char.

Using below query would give me multiple records(Number of records in Table A)

```
SELECT                                         
replace('APPLE BALL',Original_char,replacement Char) FROM Table_A
```

result would be

```
%PPLE B%LL 
APPL& BALL
```

The only way I can think of is to have a cursor over Table A which would be a laborious activity.

Comment: I think I got the answer.. .Put all the 'Original_char' to one string(String A).. Using listagg function. did the same with 'Replacement_char'(String B) .. Now I just use %XLATE over my String where I need to change it.. I have still not implemented the XLATE part but it should work

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT                                         
replace('APPLE BALL',Original_char,replacement Char) FROM Table_A
```

Your code replace the string "APPLE BALL" for every line in Table A ... 
1 time the replacement is A -> %
2 time i replace B -> & but to the original string.

You must elaborate the string, after get the result and elaborate it again... 
...You need an iteration, maybe a procedure can help you.

Somenthing like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE
    SCHEMA/PROCEDURE NAME
    (
    )
    LANGUAGE SQL
    SPECIFIC SCHEMA/PROCEDURE NAME
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    MODIFIES SQL DATA

BEGIN
    DECLARE END_C1_SRS SMALLINT DEFAULT 0 ;
    DECLARE STRING_TO_MODIFY       CHAR(10) DEFAULT 'APPLE BALL' ;    

    DECLARE C1_SRS CURSOR FOR
    select replace(STRING_TO_MODIFY,Original_char,replacement Char) FROM Table_A

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET END_C1_SRS = -1 ;
    OPEN  C1_SRS ;
    SET END_C1_SRS = 0 ;
    FETCH_C1_SRS:
    LOOP

        FETCH C1_SRS
        INTO
        STRING_TO_MODIFY
        IF END_C1_SRS = -1 THEN
            LEAVE FETCH_C1_SRS ;
        END IF ;                                                        ) ;
    END LOOP FETCH_C1_SRS ;
    CLOSE C1_SRS ;
END ;
```

Comment: THanks.. Here is the solution I have decided to go with:Put all the 'Original_char' to one string(String A).. Using listagg function. did the same with 'Replacement_char'(String B) .. Now I just use %XLATE over my String where I need to change it.. I have still not implemented the XLATE part but it should work

Answer (score 0):

Nest the replace function.

```
replace(
replace(
replace(mystring,'A','a')
,'B', 'b')
,'C,'c')
```

Comment: IRL I wouldn't do this.  It prevents transparency.

Comment: THanks.. But this may not be suitable for my condition as I do not know how many Nested Replace would be there, It would depend on the number of records in Table A. But Thanks a lot for this as I could use in some other places.I think I got the answer.. .Put all the 'Original_char' to one string(String A).. Using listagg function. did the same with 'Replacement_char'(String B) .. Now I just use %XLATE over my String where I need to change it.. I have still not implemented the XLATE part but it should work

Comment: Yep IRL life I might replace " & " ," and " but that's about it.

Comment: Thanks Danny. Will keep that in mind when we are actually deciding on what values to be added..

Comment: Hi, Could you please let me know the reason why You think why "&" and others needs to be replaced. is it because the parser outside IBMI would not be able to read these? Could You kindly explain a little bit on this.

Comment: IRL I don't change client data but the & was messing up something so I changed it to and.  Not a best practice.

Answer (score 0):

THanks..  .Put all the 'Original_char' to one string(String A).. Using listagg function. did the same with 'Replacement_char'(String B) .. Now I just use %XLATE over my String where I need to change it.. I have still not implemented the XLATE part but it should work